# mod_tileを利用した地図タイルサーバにShapefileを追加したい

Tags: linux, postgresql, openstreetmap, mapnik

以下のサイトの手順でOpenStreetMapのデータを利用した地図タイルサーバを作成しました。
http://qiita.com/nyampire/items/13ed805ac3ccaff3baf9
Linux(Lubuntu14.04),Apache(mod_tile),Mapnik,PostgreSQL(PostGIS)を利用しています。

上記で作成したサーバに別途用意したShapefileデータを反映させたいのですが方法がわかりません。
Shapefileが追加された地図と追加されていない地図を切り替えて表示させたいです。